# Why equals() method does not work if I add a punctuation mark after a word?

Tags: java, arrays, string, search

I am trying to find if a word exists in a string and how many times it occurred. The code is working fine unless the word I am trying to find has a punctuation mark after it. How can I fix this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input the string: ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input the substring to be search : ");
        String sub = sc.nextLine();
        if (str.contains(sub)) {
            System.out.println("The substring exists in the string.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The substring does not exist in the string.");
        }
        int count = 0;
        String temp[] = str.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            if (sub.equals(temp[i])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            System.out.println(sub + " has been found " + count + " times");
        } else {
            System.out.println(sub + " has not been found yet");
        }
    }
```

run:

```
Input the string: 
Hello I am mad. Are you mad?
Input the substring to be search : 
mad
The substring exists in the string
mad has not been found yet
```

Comment: equals naturally won't work if you split by " ", since then punctuation marks are considered part of the word. but contains should.

Comment: Can you perhaps also give us the input that you try which is causing problems. Also, what kind of problem are you facing exactly? Is it throwing some exception?

Comment: Change `str.split(" ")` to `str.split("\\W+")`, so non-word characters are eliminated too.

Comment: Sorry my bad. contains method works but equals does not. Also I edited the post and added the output.

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks everyone. Have a great day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace all punctuation marks using the following line:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
```

Comment: Good answer, but maybe that should be done to both `str` and `sub`, so that words like `don't` will still be found. Or a more complex regex that doesn't eliminate punctuation in the middle of a word, like `don't` and `sugar-free`.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you have this string in `str` variable:

> Hello I am mad. Are you mad?

and you do `String temp[] = str.split(" ")`, so then `temp` will contain values "Hello", "I", "am", "mad.", "Are", "you" and "mad?". You're then testing if any of them equal to "mad", and none of them equal - not any one of them has the same contents. Based on this information and combined with [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64792885/365237), you should see what is the problem and one way of working around it.